# Windows 7 guest fails to boot on Fedora 20 host

Tags: fedora, windows, virtualbox, virt-manager

In `virt-manager` Windows boots (in safe mode) up to loading `classpnp.sys`. CPU usage then stays at 100%. In VirtualBox I get a blue-screen-of-death right after loading `classpnp.sys` and then it reboots.

The image worked fine on Fedora 19. I checked Fedora 20 known bugs and Google but could not find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the image still work on Fedora 19 ? As you have a problem with both KVM and VBox, it is possible the image is corrupt (corruption happens)

Comment: I just reinstalled Fedora 19 and the image works fine... By the way, thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: Glad you got it solved, sorry you had to re-install.